# ActionView::Template::Error (singleton can't be dumped)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using gem 'jbuilder_cache_multi' for cache my json responses. I am encountering a strange error when i hit my api from my ios native app. Below is the error i got:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (singleton can't be dumped):
2:
3: json.orders do
4:   json.cache! ['v1', I18n.locale, @orders] do
5:     json.cache_collection! @orders, key: ['v1', I18n.locale] do |order|
6:       json.partial! 'order', order: order
7:     end
8:   end

app/views/api/v1/orders/index.json.jbuilder:5:in `block (2 levels) in
```

Request is:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/orders?page=2&q%5Bmerchant_id_eq%5D=1&q%5Bs%5D=created_at+asc&q%5Bstate_not_in%5D%5B%5D=composing&q%5Bstate_not_in%5D%5B%5D=distributed&q%5Bstate_not_in%5D%5B%5D=canceled"
```

Can anyone help in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the fields that you are returning might be `nil`. You need to `to_s` it. Kindly examine the values.